# Annoying errors in sections of plot

Tags: plotting

Not a major problem, but for some reason, *Mathematica* outputs unevaluated diagonal sections in what should be a step plot:

```
Plot[{PrimePi[x]}, {x, 0, 200}]
```

[image]

Incidentally, I am using v 8.0.1.0 on a Windows 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this kind of plot `DiscretePlot` is probably the best choice:

```
DiscretePlot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, 200}, Filling -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to have perfect vertical lines joining the steps, `ListPlot` would be a good alternative:

```
t1 = Table[{x, PrimePi[x]}, {x, 0, 200}];
t2 = Table[{x + 1, PrimePi[x]}, {x, 0, 200}];
ListPlot[Riffle[t1, t2], Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries, many thanks - the bottom plot is what I was really after! :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the explanation of why `Plot` does not produce an accurate graph is easily inferred from the other answers:  `Plot` *samples* points in constructing a plot.  For a function with many discrete jumps, `Plot` may not detect all of them with the automatically chosen sample points.  [Sjoerd's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57) answer shows the best ways of dealing with plotting `PrimePi`, but to get `Plot` to work there are a couple of approaches.

First, one might increase the number of sample points with the option `PlotPoints`.  The initials points are at the minimum bisected once, so for the domain `{x, 0, 200}`, one should expect that about half the integers, or `PlotPoints -> 100` will be about the minimum needed to produce a pretty good graph.  There may still be a perceptible angle to the "vertical" joins, but there will always be a slight angle.  One can check that `PlotPoints -> 99` still produces one slanted line around x equals 45 or 50.  Once all the steps are all detected, the recursive subdivision refines the jump.  How much recursion is done is controlled by `MaxRecursion`, which may be increased to make the jumps look vertical, if necessary.

```
Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 101]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Second, one might make use of the `Exclusions` option.  Just feed it all the discontinuities.

```
Plot[{PrimePi[x]}, {x, 0, 200}, 
 Exclusions -> Prime[Range[PrimePi[200]]], 
 ExclusionsStyle -> ColorData[1][1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's a variation on Sjoerd's `ListPlot` method, using `Prime` for the x coordinate instead of `PrimePi` for the y coordinate.

```
p0 = Prime[Range[PrimePi@200]] ~Append~ 200;  (* x coords of jumps, plus endpoint *)
t1 = Transpose[{p0, Range[0, PrimePi@200]}];
t2 = Transpose[{Most[p0] ~Prepend~ 0, Range[0, PrimePi@200]}];
ListPlot[Riffle[t2, t1], Joined -> True]
(* output looks the same *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You looking for something like this?

```
Plot[{PrimePi[x]}, {x, 0, 200}, Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 1050]
```

[image]

By the way you don't need `{}` just this input will be enough for plotting

```
Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, 200}, Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 1050]
```

For more info please see this [http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PrimePi.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/documentation-search.html?query=PrimePi&lang=en&forward=off) where you will see the plot of `PrimePi[x]`.

To see the **no diagonal sections** - let's try for `x=0..20`

[image]

For a large domain - let's try `x=100..200`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why the basic `plot` produces the above output though?

Comment: Yes, I realised that :)

Comment: Had a look at the link - but could see no mention of issue in question ...

Comment: It's obvious that you will not see the diagonal sections clearly because you chose `x=0..200`.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: I realise that if I take a smaller range, no diagonal sections will appear, if this is what you mean - but this wasn't really the essence of my question ;)

Comment: For small domain you can clearly see that there is no diagonal section and the plot is exactly like a step plot, isn't this you wanted? Now for large domain it seems like diagonal appearing in the plot but infact there is no diagonal. The problem you are facing is with the appearance and for that I have used `Mesh` and `PlotPoints`.