# Plotting using IntegerListPlot

Tags: plotting

I can't seem to implement IntegerListPlot, or find anything about it in the documentation. I can only assume it a custom function.

It comes from this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html). I downloaded the *Mathematica* notebook, but can't seem to replicate the plot. Here is the code used:

```
RiemannFSum[x_?NumericQ] := Total[PrimePi[x^(1/#)]/# & /@ Range[Floor[Log[2, x]]]]

Show[Block[{$DisplayFunction = Identity}, {IntegerListPlot[PrimePi[Range[50]], 
PlotStyle -> Black], IntegerListPlot[RiemannFSum /@ Range[50]]}], AxesLabel ->
TraditionalForm /@ {x, {StyleForm[HoldForm[f[x]], FontColor -> Red], 
StyleForm[PrimePi[x], FontColor -> Black]}}]
```

which *should* generate this:

[image]

For me though, it just generates an error message. Using ListPlot works, but is not the desired result:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work! Please have a look at `DiscretePlot` in the doc.

```
RiemannFSum[x_?NumericQ] := Total[PrimePi[x^(1/#)]/# & /@ Range[Floor[Log[2, x]]]];
With[{int = Range[50]},ListLinePlot[{RiemannFSum /@ int, PrimePi[int]},
     InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},AxesLabel ->
     (TraditionalForm /@ {x,Row@{StyleForm[HoldForm[f[x]], FontColor -> Red], ",", 
        StyleForm[PrimePi[x], FontColor -> Black]}})]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your solution - works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37421/5478) that [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) gave you?

```
intplot[f_, max_, min_: 1] := Riffle[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, min, max}], 
                                     Table[{x + 1, f[x]}, {x, min, max}]];

RiemannFSum[x_?NumericQ] := Total[PrimePi[x^(1/#)]/# & /@ Range[Floor[Log[2, x]]]]


ListPlot[{intplot[RiemannFSum, 50], intplot[PrimePi, 50]}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have just realised that I could have applied that principle here :o